# How can I export/import contribution pages and event pages from one site to another

Tags: civievent, drupal, import, contribution-page, export

I want to export contribution and event pages from one Drupal7 site to another Drupal7 site.

Is this doable, any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: To clarify: you only want to copy the contribution pages, not the actual contributions - and the event pages, not participants?  Are they the same civi version?

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible (but I've not tried it ...) using the API for Event and ContributionPage:
`civicrm_api3('Event', 'get', ...)` to get them from one system and 
`civicrm_api3('Event', 'create', ...)` on the other.

Take a look at the API explorer on your system (Support >> Developer >> API explorer).

Unless you have loads of them, it might be just as quick doing it manually!

Answer (score 1):

It sort of depends on what you mean by eg 'event page'; do you mean also taking over all the information to create the location, the price set, the Profiles etc, or actually just the info in a row of civicrm_event.

If the latter then you can check what you can grab and insert via sql (eg if you have something like Sequel Pro, you can click on a row in the table, the right click and "Copy as SQL insert" and then at the other end, just paste as a query.